# Failed to generate java classes from xsd using binding

Tags: java, xml, binding, xsd

I have a lot of XSD in path to generate java classes. In my bindings file I have:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../aiseo/xsd/AiseoTypy.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

</jaxb:bindings>
```

but it throw error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.1.1:wsdl2java (generate-sources-iszr) on project iszr-dataset: Execution generate-sources-iszr of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.1.1:wsdl2java failed: file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/binding/bindings.xml [16,79]: "file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/aiseo/xsd/AiseoTypy.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for "file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/ais3/xsd/Ais3Typy.xsd"?
```

so I tried it to change it what it advise me

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../ais3/xsd/Ais3Typy.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

</jaxb:bindings>
```

but it throw error and advise my to use previous XSD.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.1.1:wsdl2java (generate-sources-iszr) on project iszr-dataset: Execution generate-sources-iszr of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-    plugin:3.1.1:wsdl2java failed: file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/binding/bindings.xml [15,77]: "file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/ais3/xsd/Ais3Typy.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for "file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/aiseo/xsd/AiseoTypy.xsd"?
```

So I am really confused why it still throw error in both cases

Both XSD should be in path because as you can see it advise me.

UPDATE:

after debugging I found where is problem. In first case it generated some classes and throw error when start procesing wsdl Ais3...

OK:

```
[DEBUG] Calling wsdl2java with args: [-encoding, UTF-8, -d, /home/hudect/git/ais3/backend/common-reactor/iszr-dataset/target/generated-sources/cxf, -b, file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/binding/bindings.xml, -xjc-Xinheritance, -verbose, file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/aiseo/wsdl/AiseoCtiAifo.wsdl]
Loading FrontEnd jaxws ...
Loading DataBinding jaxb ...
wsdl2java -encoding UTF-8 -d /some/path/generated-sources/cxf -b file:/home/some/path/resources/wsdl/binding/bindings.xml -xjc-Xinheritance -verbose file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/aiseo/wsdl/AiseoCtiAifo.wsdl
wsdl2java - Apache CXF 3.1.1
```

Error:

```
[DEBUG] Calling wsdl2java with args: [-encoding, UTF-8, -d, /some/path/generated-sources/cxf, -b, file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/binding/bindings.xml, -xjc-Xinheritance, -verbose, file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/ais3/wsdl/Ais3RrcCtiHromadneAifo.wsdl]
Loading FrontEnd jaxws ...
Loading DataBinding jaxb ...
wsdl2java -encoding UTF-8 -d /some/path/generated-sources/cxf -b file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/binding/bindings.xml -xjc-Xinheritance -verbose file:/some/path/resources/wsdl/ais3/wsdl/Ais3RrcCtiHromadneAifo.wsdl
wsdl2java - Apache CXF 3.1.1
```

but I dont understand why it must be in path ? In XSD ais3 is used Ais3Typy and in aiseo is used  aiseoTypy. Is there option how to use just one binding file where all this declaration are written. I know I can divided it to more file and create more execution in maven but I have more then 10 of this file *Typy.xsd so I want to just one binding.

Answer (score 0):

The path for schemaLocation is not correct.

It should be relative to your binding file.

If you have something like

```
workspace/
  -  binding/xyz.xjb
  -  xsd/file.xsd
```

Youd should have :

```
schemaLocation="../xsd/file.xsd"
```

Comment: please trust me. Path is OK. I need to edit it because in log is my absulte path which I dont want to public so I edit it myself and there can my some copy/paste error